# How can I reset many radio button groups by selecting a specific radio button group

Tags: javascript, php, html, radio-button

I have three different groups named "type" below. Under those groups are other groups of buttons with different names. When I choose any of the "type" named radio buttons, I would like to clear(reset) all other radio buttons that may be selected beside the "type" group radio button which is selected.

```
         <input type="radio" value="three egg breakfast" name="type">
         <img src="threeeggbreakfasttext.jpg" class="roundcorn">

               <input type="radio" value="white toast" name="threeeggtoast">
               <img src="whitetext.jpg" width="44" height="26" class="roundcorn">      
            
              <label><input type="radio" value="whole wheat toast" name="threeeggtoast">
              <img src="wholewheattext.jpg" width="108" height="26" class="roundcorn"></label>

              <label><input type="radio" value="hash brown" name="threeeggside">
              <img src="hashbrowntext.jpg" class="roundcorn"></label>    
              
              <label><input type="radio" value="grits" name="threeeggside">
              <img src="gritstext.jpg" width="44" height="26" class="roundcorn"></label>




        <input type="radio" value="ultimate omelette" name="type">
        <img src="ultimateomelettetext.jpg" class="roundcorn">

                <label> <input type="radio" value="bacon" name="omelettemeat">
                <img src="bacontext.jpg" class="roundcorn"></label>
                   
                <label> <input type="radio" value="ham" name="omelettemeat">
                <img src="hamtext.jpg" class="roundcorn"></label>
                        
                <label><input type="radio" value="white toast" name="omelettetoast">
                <img src="/whitetext.jpg" class="roundcorn"></label>
                    
                <label><input type="radio" value="whole wheat toast" name="omelettetoast">
                <img src="wholewheattext.jpg" class="roundcorn"></label>


                   


       </label><input type="radio" value="pancakes" name="type">
       <img src="pancakestext.jpg" class="roundcorn"></label>

                <label><input type="radio" value="scrambled eggs" name="pancakeegg">
                <img src="scrambledtext.jpg" class="roundcorn"></label>
                    
                <label><input type="radio" value="eggs over easy" name="pancakeegg" >
                <img src="overeasytext.jpg" class="roundcorn"></label>
                   
                <label><input type="radio" value="sausage patties" name="pancakemeat" >
                <img src="sausagepattiestext.jpg" class="roundcorn"></label>
                   
                <label><input type="radio" value="beef smoked sausage" name="pancakemeat">
                <img src="beefsmokedsausagetext.jpg" class="roundcorn"></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const typeInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name=type][type=radio]`) // consider other name
const radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`input[type=radio]`) // consider other name

typeInputs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
  radioInputs.forEach(input => {
    if (input !== target)
      input.checked = false;
  })
}));
```

Comment: Agustin! - Bravo! Very nice solution that works flawlessly! Thank you!